# Firefox with two different version on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, firefox

I already had "`Mozila Firefox Version 54`" installed on my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

I had downloaded updated .jar of "`Mozila Firefox Version 57`" from Firefox Site. and Extracted It.

Now When I click Mozila Firefox Icon from Start Menu or Shortcut Launcher, It opens up `Version 54`. and When I run command "./firefox" command from extracted JAR. It opens up `Version 57`.

How can I open "`Version 57`" from Start Menu or Shortcut Launcher on Linux Ubuntu machine 16.04?

Which steps I am missing after Installation?

Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: In case you need only `version 57`, just change link of `/usr/bin/firefox` to `/extracted/path/of/your/downloaded/jar/firefox`.  From that on wards it will execute newer version only to which it is pointing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is obvious the mentioned Firefox icon will launch the 54 version, because the launcher is pointing to Firefox 54 executable. Whereas the version 57 you downloaded located at extracted `.jar` file.

Assuming you want to running multiple version, try creating launcher for the second existing version. So it can be execute from Unity launcher.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gedit` on the field. Then paste following text.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/path/to/unzipped/firefox
Name=Firefox 57
Comment=comment here
Icon=/path/to/icon.png
```

Fill the required field, save it as `Firefox 57.desktop`. Don't forget to make it executable: `chmod +x Firefox\ 57.desktop`.

For more details, consider read http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2400491.